# Is there a way to toggle temporarily (hide/show) a leaflet map (specifically under react)?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, show-hide, react-leaflet

I have a multi-partition site and the user switches between the partitions.

On one of the partitions there is a leaflet map. When the user navigates to it, it loads and when they navigate away it obviously closes since it is no longer being rendered.

The issue I'm trying to solve is to minimize the refresh time.  Obviously leaflet takes at least some time to build the map, pull in tiles, determine positions, throw on extra layers, etc.  and while very short, it is still an obvious "refresh" to the user, additionally this is on an internal network that is bandwidth limited, so every time the same tiles have to be re-downloaded impacts (although small) the network for other resources.

Instead of removing the Map when the user switches partitions is there a quick way to simply "minimize" it so it is imperceptible to the user? Even if it is just setting a width/height of 0.  This way the map can be in a "warm" state for quick display.  Or is there a way to save the required portions for quick re-renders.

each time I switch to the partition, all the images are re-laoded:[image]

Comment: What do you mean with multi-partition, could you share how your code is structured and a print screen from your site? 
I often use Tabs and the library I use have the option to keep tabs mounted:
https://mantine.dev/core/tabs/

Comment: That will take some work to get it down to a min example... but basically I have 3 different "web pages" that the user can switch between.  And if they switch to the map partition/tab then it renders, switch off that page and it goes away (basically an if statement before <MapContainer>) .  I'll take a look at the tab views.

Comment: @Disco, just confirming that you have a leaflet map loaded on a tab and when you switch to it or back to it, it doesn't reload the map images? have you looked at the f12 developer options to confirm? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could render another element to be in the same space as the map, but but a higher z-index.

Comment: Good idea... The other page is a wall of text with each line an independent presentation of data that is updated often (over a period of a few seconds), and is much greater in size/length then the map.  So would get challenging to make everything line up with different browser sizes.